# Object Array, C#, Cannot access individual element inside in array

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm creating Questionnaire application in window form by using C# . And i try to access individual element in array but the program prints all the element in the array.
Code :

```
 public object arrayq (int d)
    {
        object[] question = new object[3];

        question[0] = Q1.Text;
        question[1] = Q2.Text + (Q2.Visible = true) + (question2.Visible = true) + (question1.Visible = false) + (Q1.Visible = false);
        question[2] = Q3.Text + (question3.Visible = true);
        return question[d];
    }
```

This is the following code in the button that i try to access into the array.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        if (Q1a.Checked || Q1b.Checked || Q1c.Checked)
        {
            int k = 1;
            arrayq(k);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter your answer" + "\n" + "Please click Skip Button if you want to skip the question","Warning message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        }

    }
```

The program accesses question[1] and question [2] in the array and printout the question 2 and 3 at same time. I don't understand why the program do it .

Many thanks

Comment: `question[1] = Q2.Text + (Q2.Visible = true) + (qu...` => Are you sure it returns what you actually want?

Comment: yes, it is. The question 1 is invisible and question 2 is visible .

Comment: Instead of toggling the visibility on and off for each question, I would recommend that each time you call the arrayq-method, you set all questions to invisible, and then afterwards set the question you want to be visible.

Comment: Yes, I did do it, in the default of the Label , i changed Visible : false. Only the Question 1 I put visible : true in default because it is a first question. In my command , i didn't call arrayq[2] why the program did it ? . I only call question[1] (arrayq[1]).

Comment: Why dont you create a Question class and set properties to it then simply point to the proper index in the array instead of that very complicated "i create an array to return a single value of that array"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By running your code, in both cases when Q1, Q2 and Q3 (labels?) are visible or hidden, I'd expect it to hide Q1 and become visible Q2(from question[1] and Q3(from question[2]).

By running arrayq(int d), the program reads all lines, regardless of what is returned.

What I'd recommend is to use conditional statements like:

```
public object arrayq (int d)
{
    if(d=1)
    {
        Q2.Visible = true;
        question2.Visible = true;
        question1.Visible = false;
        Q1.Visible = false
    }
    else if(d=2){
        question3.Visible = true
    }
    object[] question = new object[3];

    question[0] = Q1.Text;
    question[1] = Q2.Text;
    question[2] = Q3.Text ;
    return question[d];
}
```

Comment: in default Q2,Q3 are hidden, yes,it is. It is a label.

Answer (score 0):

create a simple class to help you sort things out such as this

```
public class Question
{
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public bool IsVisible { get; set; }
    public bool IsChecked { get; set; }

    public Question()
    {
        SetDefault(0, "", false, false);
    }
    public void Question(int questionId, string text, bool isVisible, bool isChecked)
    { 
        SetDefault(questionId, text, isVisible, isChecked);
    }

    private void SetDefault(int questionId, string text, bool isVisible, bool isChecked)
    {
       QuestionId = questionId;
       Text = text;
       IsVisible = isVisible;
       IsChecked = isChecked;
    }
}
```

keep a local variable in your form like the following and fill it with your data :

```
List<Question> Questions = new List<Question>();
...
...
private void GenerateQuestions()
{
    Questions.Clear();
    Questions.Add(new Question(1, Q1.Text, Q1.Visible, Q1.IsChecked));
    Questions.Add(new Question(2, Q2.Text, Q2.Visible, Q2.IsChecked));
    // and so on
}
```

now to get a specific question (i.e question #1) simply do :

```
Question question1 = Questions.Find(q=> q.QuestionId == 1);
```

Comment: Hello, can i have a quick question please ? Where will I put the GenerateQuestion method ? Is it in my main form ? If yes, my program keeps saying the program doesn't contain the method(IsChecked). I have tried to put the GenerateQuestion method inside Question class but the program didn't recognize the variable from the main form ( Do we need to try inheritance ?) . Sorry because I'm is very new with C# and I just want to learn new things. Many thanks for your help

Comment: The class `Question` contain different properties, you can add or remove to it as much as you need. And the `Q1.IsChecked` was simply an example on how to instanciate the class and fill the data you will need. That ischecked fills the property of the same name in the class. I assumed Q1 is a checkbox or something like that.

Comment: https://www.mediafire.com/?85dsic6atb5jw81 This is my file at the moment , I will need to include the IsCheck function later on . At the moment, the program has a problem with the constructor, Could u have a look please, tks

Comment: You seems to understand the logic of adding / remove properties. the generate method you can call it in the load of the form but they shouldn't be filled from control text values. the controls should be filled with values of the `List<Question>`

Comment: Could you fix the problem please :? I kind of don't what I need to do . Tks

Comment: Sorry but i can't. I follow the site rules. You need to take basic programming classes to fix this. You can try to fix by yourself and try to apply solution and if you are stuck or have issue at specific points you can post a NEW question with some code and what you have done so far and what you expect and people will help you. follow these [guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: tks, i will try it again

Comment: Question question1 = Questions.Find(q=> q.QuestionId == 1); I fix the problem with the constructor, but how can i call each element in the list ?

Comment: [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is all you need to know about list.